# Deriving equation with Hamilton's Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

Given that kinetic energy is given as $T=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^l\rho u_t^2dx$, where $\rho$ is a uniform linear density constant, potential energy is given as $U=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^l \mu u_{xx}^2dx$, where $\mu>0$ is flexural rigidity. Also given: $u=u(x,t)$, $u=u_x=0$ at $x=0$ and $x=l$.

How does one derive the equation of motion $\rho u_{tt}+\mu u_{xxxx}=0$?

I took the generalized coordinates to be $u$ and $x$ and obtained $$\rho\int\limits_0^l u_{tt}=0.$$

With the second part, I tried integration by parts, but did not obtain the desired result. Would appreciate some input.

Comment: Put up the action $S = \int L{\rm d}t$ where $L = T - U$. Consider a variation $\delta u$ to $u$ this leads to a variation $\delta S = \int {\rm d}x{\rm d}t \left[ \rho u_t \delta u_t - \mu u_{xx}\delta u_{xx} \right]$. Apply integration by parts on each of the two terms (the $t$-integral for the first integral and the $x$-integral for the second integral) to bring it to the form $\delta S = \int {\rm d}x{\rm d}t[\cdots]\delta u$ which gives you the equation of motion by Hamilton's Principle (stationary action $\delta S = 0$ so $[\cdots] = 0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hamilton's principle states that the first variation of the Lagrangian should be zero. That is,

$$\partial (T-U) = 0.$$

To calculate the first variation, consider a test function $v\in C^\infty_c$ and compute

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{2h}\left(\int \rho (u_t+hv_t)^2 - \mu (u_{xx}+hv_{xx})^2 -\rho u_t^2 + \mu u_{xx}^2 \right) = \frac{1}{2} \int 2\rho u_tv_t-2\mu  u_{xx}v_{xx}.$$

Integration by parts (note that we integrate by parts 2 times for the space derivatives) gives

$$0= \partial (T-U) = \int - \rho u_{tt} v - \mu u_{xxxx} v = - \int (\rho u_{tt}+\mu u_{xxxx})v.$$

Since $v$ is arbitrary we deduce that $\rho u_{tt} +\mu u_{xxxx}=0$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! if $u(0,t)=u(l, t)=0$ then can you please give a clue on how to derive natural boundary conditions for a stationary function? I don't see where to begin from, since I don't even quite understand the question, in the sense of what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: This should be helpful to you: http://www.math.odu.edu/~jhh/ch44.PDF  however if you are having trouble understanding the question then we should slow down to truly identify the problem.  The natural boundary conditions should arise from the integration by parts. I suppressed the boundary terms, but if you leave them, you should quickly see the necessary natural boundary conditions.

Comment: I did the integration by parts and got the same result as you. But the other terms were $0$ because of the given $u=u_x=0$, and because $v(l)=v(0)=0$. So the terms vanished. Do you mean we should reconsider the terms which vanished from a different perspective?